# How do I add a non-null column, copy the data from another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have a table A as follows:

```
dbo.A
____________
ID (PK, int, not null)
RequestID (FK, int, not null)
AssignedUserID (FK, nvarchar(128), not null)
```

Due to changes in process, we are adding a column 'IssuedUserID' and removing the 'not null' constraint on AssignedUserID.  This table tracks something which is Issued by a user and then Assigned by a user, and due to changes in process, these are no longer required to be the same user.

Thus, for existing rows, IssuedUserID will match AssignedUserID.  Moving forward, AssignedUserId will be null until the row is assigned.

I know I could write a script that will add IssuedUserID as a nullable field, update it to match AssignedUserId, and then alter it to be non-null, but I'd like to do it as part of the column creation if practical.

Is there a syntax to populate a row's new column's data based on another column's data?

We are using MS SQL Server 2012, if that matters.

Comment: Use a computed column.

Comment: @Rahul: Assume I only know the basics of SQL, and make that an answer.  I have no clue what a computed column is, or if it is appropriate here.  Please educate me!

Comment: If I understand the situation, a computed column will not work for this case. The OP wants all current values in the new column to = [AssignedUserID], but future values may be set to values other than [AssignedUserID].

Comment: My approach would be to add your new column, and run an UPDATE operation. Shout if you need help with that (unless someone offers a better solution).

Answer (score 1):

You want to make the existing column nullable, and add a new non-nullable column. It is easier (and faster) to work the other way around; add a nullable column, then rename the columns.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.A ADD NewUserID nvarchar(128) NULL
UPDATE dbo.A SET NewUserID = AssignedUserID
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.A.AssignedUserID', 'IssuedUserID', 'COLUMN'
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.A.NewUserID', 'AssignedUserID', 'COLUMN'
```

If necessary, add an index on AssignedUserID; any existing index on AssignedUserID has automatically gone to IssuedUserID.

As far as I know, the `UPDATE` statement is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [COMPUTED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) column. Little excerpt from the MSDN spec

> A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in
>   the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column
>   expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for
>   the column to which it belongs. You can specify an expression for a
>   computed column

An example would be something like below. So in this case `COMPUTED_ID` will be one more than value of `ID`.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(10), COMPUTED_ID AS ID+1 PERSISTED)
```

In your case you can do something like

```
dbo.A
____________
ID (PK, int, not null)
RequestID (FK, int, not null)
AssignedUserID (FK, nvarchar(128), not null)
IssuedUserID AS ISNULL(AssignedUserID,'0') PERSISTED
```

See [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/03/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and%C2%A0performance/) for more information on the same.

**EDIT:**

In that case, the only approach would be the way you initially thought of trying but instead of `UPDATE` single row you can go for a quicker approach like

Create another similar table

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_A
(
    ID (PK, int, not null)
    RequestID (FK, int, not null)
    AssignedUserID (FK, nvarchar(128), not null)
    IssuedUserID (nvarchar(128), not null)
)
```

Do a `INSERT INTO SELECT` like

```
INSERT INTO NEW_A 
SELECT RequestID,
AssignedUserID,
ISNULL(AssignedUserID,'0') AS IssuedUserID
FROM A
```

`DROP` the existing table `A`

```
DROP TABLE A
```

`RENAME` the new table to `A`

```
sp_rename NEW_A, A
```

Comment: This wouldn't work in this case, as only existing rows will match the other column.  Future rows can be different...that's why there's a new column being created.

Comment: @Jeff, check edited answer (the `EDIT:` part). Hope this helps.